# Is there a way to disable just one input in a modal window in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog

I have a very basic Shiny App. The user clicks the "Add Data" button and can save their answers, which render on the app. They can also click "Edit Data" and the user can edit whatever they saved. That is the intention of both so everything fine so far. However, I want to format the app so that when the user clicks on "Edit Data" they can no longer edit the textInput. They should only be allowed to edit the numericInput. I want the textInput to remain so the user sees it, but they just can't edit it. Is there a way to accomplish that? Thank you.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Example Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add_data_btn", "Add Data"),
      actionButton("edit_data_btn", "Edit Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text_output"),
      textOutput("numeric_output")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  saved_text <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  saved_numeric <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_data_btn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      textInput(inputId = "text_input", label = "Enter Text"),
      numericInput(inputId = "numeric_input", label = "Enter Number 1-10", value = 1, min = 1, max = 10),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("save_btn", "Save")
      )
    ))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$save_btn, {
    saved_text(input$text_input)
    saved_numeric(input$numeric_input)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$edit_data_btn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      textInput("text_input", "Enter Text", value = saved_text()),
      numericInput("numeric_input", "Enter Number 1-10", value = saved_numeric(),  min = 1, max = 10),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("update_btn", "Update Data")
      )
    ))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$update_btn, {
    saved_text(input$text_input)
    saved_numeric(input$numeric_input)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  
  output$text_output <- renderText({
    saved_text()
  })
  
  
  output$numeric_output <- renderText({
    saved_numeric()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` function of the **shinyjs** package to display a disabled text input:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), # <--- don't forget that!!  
  titlePanel("Example Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("add_data_btn", "Add Data"),
      actionButton("edit_data_btn", "Edit Data")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("text_output"),
      textOutput("numeric_output")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  saved_text <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  saved_numeric <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$add_data_btn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      textInput(inputId = "text_input", label = "Enter Text"),
      numericInput(inputId = "numeric_input", label = "Enter Number 1-10", value = 1, min = 1, max = 10),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("save_btn", "Save")
      )
    ))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$save_btn, {
    saved_text(input$text_input)
    saved_numeric(input$numeric_input)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$edit_data_btn, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      disabled(textInput("text_input", "Enter Text", value = saved_text())),
      numericInput("numeric_input", "Enter Number 1-10", value = saved_numeric(),  min = 1, max = 10),
      footer = tagList(
        actionButton("update_btn", "Update Data")
      )
    ))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$update_btn, {
    saved_numeric(input$numeric_input)
    removeModal()
  })
  
  
  output$text_output <- renderText({
    saved_text()
  })
  
  
  output$numeric_output <- renderText({
    saved_numeric()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```